# How to change Ubuntu 18.04 system fonts?

Tags: fonts, gnome-shell

I installed Ubuntu 18.04, and I want to customize the fonts.
I have already change all the setting by tweak tool.
But the system default font not be changed, is anything I need to do?

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font for the texts highlighted in the screenshots you've posted is dictated by the GNOME shell theme.

Since generally it's not a good idea to edit system files (any update of an associated package will most probably overwrite it), you may create a custom css override in your home directory and load it from there. To do that, follow the steps below.

1. Create a directory, say `MyTheme` in `~/.themes`. (You may create `~/.themes` if it doesn't exist.)
2. Create another directory inside `MyTheme` called `gnome-shell`.
3. Create an empty document in this `gnome-shell` directory and name it `gnome-shell.css`.
4. Open this `gnome-shell.css` file with a text editor and add the following lines

   ```
   @import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css");  

   stage {
       font-family: FONT_NAME, Sans-Serif;
   }
   ```

   Change `FONT_NAME` to the font of your choice and save the file.
5. Install the [GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called the **User themes** from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).
6. Install *(GNOME) Tweaks* by running

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
7. Launch Tweaks and go to **Appearance** section. Click on the drop-down box next to "*Shell theme*". **MyTheme** should appear in the drop-down list. Select it.
8. Restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> then typing `r` and hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> (works in an Xorg session, in Wayland logout and login again).

Comment: I do it step by step, and it success.
Thank you so much, pomsky.
It is useful to me, I learned a new function.