# Dash to panel, change background color, transparency and font

Tags: themes, fonts, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Is it possible to change background color, transparency and font family in Dash to Panel? I was searching, but no success.

**OS** Ubuntu 18.04.4.

**Update**

Followed links in comment, but no success. I am using `gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel` tweak extension. Is it working with that?

[image]

Comment: The font-family is most probably dictated by the GNOME shell theme, see https://askubuntu.com/q/963667/480481 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1032709/480481

Comment: @pomsky Looks pretty good, but it is not working. I tried change for example `font-size` too, but no effect. System restarted. I am using `gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel`. Is it working with that?

Comment: @genderbee maybe you have to install the extension for your user only, not system-wide. Try installing the extension through `gnome-software` or https://extensions.gnome.org (with the gnome extensions plugin installed on your browser) or copying the `dash-to-panel@author.domain` directory in `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy, as ussually. :)

I had to

- **Install some more extensions.**

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions`

- **Reboot.**
- **Turn it on `User themes` in `Tweaks / Extensions / User themes`.**

[image]

Thank you all for your helpfulness.